# Why can't I test if correct generic view is resolved?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, tdd

I'm trying to get into TDD. Going by the book of Harry Percival I want to go in very small steps. So my first unit test should be to check if ...

```
found = resolve("/")
```

really calls the right function. So I do this assertion:

```
self.assertEqual(found.func, ListView.as_view())
```

But it tells me:

```
AssertionError: <function ListView at 0x3389668> != <function ListView at 0x35c1e60>
```

So why don't the functions match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListView.as_view()` generates new view function object at every call. So function generated in `urls.py` is a different from function generated in your test.

You can create view function one time in your `views.py` and refer to it in `urls.py` and `tests.py`:

**views.py**

```
home_view = ListView.as_view()
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^$', views.home_view, name='home'),
```

**tests.py**

```
self.assertEqual(found.func, views.home_view)
```

Comment: Thank you. What's the advantage of doing this over what @alecxe proposes?

Comment: If you have only one `ListView` in your project then @alexce's proposal is perfect.  But if there are several `ListView`s and you want to distinguish them then my approach is better.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the `__class__` ([as it is done under-the-hood for the django debug page](https://github.com/django/django/blob/932d449f001a94aa5065cda652a442e4b1dd5352/django/views/debug.py#L537)):

```
self.assertEqual(found.func.__class__, ListView)
```